# Why won't chrome follow CSS order of precedence?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align my radio buttons. They are implemented as follows :

```
<input type="radio" name="type" class="radv" value="0" />
```

Here's the style defined in the local file header :

```
<style>
input.radv
{
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin:0px;
    padding-bottom:4px;
}
</style>
```

And here's the conflicting style in my external CSS file :

```
input:not([type=submit]):not([type=file]):not([type=image]) {
 border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
 background-color:#fff;
 padding:2px;
 height:18px;
}
```

Somehow, the external "input" style is taking precendence. Shouldn't local styles be preferred over external CSS files?

Comment: Which line is taking precedence? The padding?

Comment: well i think css follow order correctly....make sure your inline css is loaded after external css...so last one will be applied to `DOM`.

Comment: Yea the padding. And how do I ensure that inline CSS is loaded last?

Comment: @DipeshParmar The order only matters if the specificity of the selector is the same. See the answer I posted now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason the rule from the external stylesheet is taking precedence is **specificity**. Being defined inside `<style>` or not does not matter.

While `:not()` itself does not give the selector weight, each attribute selector inside gives the same weight as a class would.

`input.radv` will have **total weight (0,1,1)** because of one element selector **(0,0,1)** and one class **(0,1,0)**.

`input:not([type=submit]):not([type=file]):not([type=image])` will have **total weight (0,3,1)** because of one element selector **(0,0,1)** and three attribute selectors **(0,1,0)x3** and therefore take precedence.

**NOTE: The order would only matter if the specificity was the *exact same*.**

Read more about css selector specificity here: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: Thank you. I was unaware of this.

Answer (score 1):

As Dipesh Parmar said check the order of loading inline/external css code,

if you don't want to change the order...
you can always use `!important` after the property value that you want it to be prefered:

```
<style>
input.radv
{
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin:0px;
    padding-bottom:4px !important;/*the `important` will make sure this property applies unless there is another property with `!important` value next to this one in DOM*/
}
</style>
```

Comment: How do I check the order? Thank you.

Comment: you have to check the code including order in you script, but if you can't find out.. you can always use `chrome` to inspect this element with the `Developer tools` or with firebug in `Mozilla firefox`
with chrome you can right click on the element you want to inspect its `css` properties and check the right side of the panel will appear on the bottom of the window to see all the parameters with overridden properties with a stroke line over it or the correct followed properties without that stroke line over it and you can find out the `css` file and the line number which includes this property

Comment: I have done all of that, question is how can I tweak it? I know which line is using it, but one style is in an external file while the other is in the same php's header.

Comment: external and internal will NOT effect in the order of css overriding,
there is many things effects on css overriding (order, !important, 'style' property in the element tag,...etc),
if you can explain what you mean by `tweak it` then i can help you sort it out,

and by the way you can always override all the properties by adding this css property to the tag itself:
`<input type="radio" name="type" class="radv" value="0" style="padding-bottom:4px" />`
this will override any other property even if it came at the end of DOM

Comment: Be very careful with using `!important` - while it might solve your problem right now, it is a quick and dirty solution that might end up causing more headaches than it solves in the future. Check out http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/